# Oracle Error: SELECT list inconsistent with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to understand this challenge: [SQL Contest](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

I found this solution in the challenge's discussion thread:

```
SELECT submission_date, 
(SELECT COUNT(distinct hacker_id)  
    FROM Submissions s2  
    WHERE s2.submission_date = s1.submission_date 
        AND (SELECT COUNT(distinct s3.submission_date) 
                FROM Submissions s3 WHERE s3.hacker_id = s2.hacker_id AND s3.submission_date < s1.submission_date) 
                  = (s1.submission_date - TO_DATE('2016-03-01'))),
(SELECT hacker_id from submissions s2 where s2.submission_date = s1.submission_date 
    GROUP BY hacker_id 
    ORDER BY count(submission_id) desc
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) as shit,
(SELECT hacker_name from hackers where hacker_id = shit)
FROM 
(SELECT distinct submission_date from submissions) s1
group by submission_date;
```

As the title states, I get the error that "SELECT list inconsistent with GROUP BY" which I don't understand. And if I try to run the script I get this error that I also don't understand:

> Error at Command Line : 12 Column : 56
>
> Error report - SQL Error:
>
> ORA-00904: "SHIT": invalid identifier
>
> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Comment: Ah Sorry. My first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without tables, we can't run that code.

Anyway, error you mentioned is raised in this line:

```
(SELECT hacker_name from hackers where hacker_id = shit)
                                                   ----
```

because you can't reference a column which is part of the same `select` statement. You could, for example, use a subquery or a CTE to collect shit and then reuse it afterwards. Something like this (simplified):

```
with 
-- you need S1 because you use it in A_CTE (see the "s2 join s1" part)
s1 as
  (SELECT distinct submission_date from submissions),
a_cte as
  (SELECT hacker_id as shit
   from submissions s2 join s1 on s2.submission_date = s1.submission_date   --> S1 is used here
   GROUP BY hacker_id 
   ORDER BY count(submission_id) desc
   FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
  )
-- finally, you can now join HACKERS to A_CTE and use that SHIT
select hacker_name
from hackers h join a_cte on h.hacker_id = a.shit
```

Comment: Still not getting the right results in Oracle but at least all the errors are gone :)